# JQuery .index() issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having an issue with the following bit of code. I'm trying to retrieve the index of the `li` element that is currently being hovered over.

HTML:

```
<div id="featured">
         <ul>
              <li class="active">foo</li>
              <li class="">bar</li>
              <li class="">giraffe</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#featured ul li').hover(function(){
             console.log($(this).index()); //returns -1
             console.log($('li').index($(this))); //returns integers beginning at 6
        });
    });
```

The first option in javascript I used returns a -1 and the second returns integers starting at 6.

I'm lost. Please someone show me what I'm doing wrong! :)

Also, I am using the version of jQuery embedded withing my drupal install, 1.2.6

Edit:Fixed the syntax on the second console.log of my JS example.

Comment: idk.. `console.log($(this).index());` works fine for me on this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/Yr9sU/ ..... does it causeyou issues? I'm using google chrome

Comment: @mazlix: When you change jQuery to 1.2.6, it returns -1.

Comment: If all the folks testing just this markup are getting correct numbers, then perhaps it's your markup. Possibilities: 1: do you have more than one element with the id `featured`? 2: do you have nested `li` elements in your html? These could cause surprising results. t

Comment: with jQuery 1.2.6 it doesn't work, but you can use a workaroun, look at my answer

Comment: I really recommend you use a newer jQuery (see my answer)

Comment: I don't have the ability to change the version of jQuery unfortunately, so I'm stuck with 1.2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with you version of jquery, i tested it with 1.2.6, 1.3.2 and it worked as you said, i tested it with jQuery 1.4.4 and it's working. Have you considered upgrading the version of jquery or loading a newer vwrsion and using noConflict()?

EDIT - you could use this as a workaround:

```
    $('#featured ul li').hover(function(event){
         console.log($(this).prevAll('li').length); //returns 0,1,2
   });
```

fiddle (tested IE9, FF5 and Chrome 12): http://jsfiddle.net/WWw4n/

Comment: What browser are you using to make it not work? Using chrome and 1.2.6 seems to be working fine?

Comment: @Jesse i'm using firefox 5, i got it to work in another way (which is cross browser or at least it works on IE9, FF5 and Chrome 12)

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is off.  Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/4NA3T/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#featured ul li').hover(function(){
             alert($(this).index()); //returns -1
             alert(('li').index($(this))); //returns integers beginning at 6
        });
    });
```

Can you explain the syntax to me for the 2nd alert?  How come it doesn't need the $ notation? (new to jQuery)

Comment: Read the question: this is the right fiddle for testing (jQuery 1.2.6): http://jsfiddle.net/4NA3T/1/

Comment: ah, dyslexia.  I was using 1.6.2 instead of 1.2.6

Comment: You're right, my syntax on the second line was off. It was correct in my code, so it must have been a copy paste error. I fixed it in the OP. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this;

```
 $('#featured li').index($(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

**Upgrade your jquery:**  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Lots of sites use the newest version 1.6.2, which is hosted on google CDN, it's likely many ppl who visit will have that in cache... if not... then whatever it's a small file.. You will save yourself a lot of headaches by using the newest version.