# Reason to use older versions of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, version-control

I just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6795373/763116) question about how to fix something in `jQuery 1.2.6` and don't understand why people would use older jQuery versions? What benefits/reasons are there?

To me I thought the answer was obviously to update to the newest jQuery, but there must be reasons why most of the responses don't say that.

**EDIT:** 
I understand being....say *one* version behind, especially when a new version just came out.. but being more than say... 3 versions behind? I don't see how the effort of making something work in the newer version would be more than making future things work with the older version.

---

Thanks!

Comment: so are there lots of examples of code that doesn't work with the newest version? I would think the opposite is true though, you could get more help/documentation on the newest (or maybe 2nd newest) versions of jQuery

Comment: Some of the people that run high up time applications like to change as little as possible to introduce the minimum amount of risk as possible. Changing a whole library is considered a big change where changing a method or two in a library is considered much a smaller change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Newer versions often new ways of doing the same thing and infrequently but do break backward compatibility.

Sometimes, the sheer effort of regression testing (after upgrade) your site can be a deterrent.

Also, if there are other third party plugins that rely on a older version, then until they upgrade, you can't.

Answer (score 5):

The same reason many corporate intranets still run ie6, there are legacy systems that treat "bugs" as "features" and would have to rewrite and debug code that already works on the older version...

Comment: ugh... **raises hand indicating experience in this nightmare.**

Answer (score 2):

if it's not broken, don't change it :))

Comment: In the questions I linked to it WAS broken... but I disagree... unless it's a webpage you never plan on changing, isn't it best to be at the latest version because all the latest plugins, answers on SO, etc. will be using that version

Comment: I wasn't referring to jQuery 1.2.6, I was talking about the applications that use jQuery 1.2.6 (in answering your question). If the applications are running fine, the rule of thumb is, it should be best left like that; unless you have the time and resource to do the update, testing and fixing. Of course, it is best to have the latest version, but in huge project/application, it's not always that simple.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the situation.  If you're managing a large application that uses jQuery 1.2.6 or something old (like 1.3.2), it may not be easy to keep up with deploying new versions of the application with updated jQuery libraries.  You'll have to keep up on breaking changes (like the changes b/w 1.5 and 1.6 with the `data` and `attr` changes).  If your app uses jQuery extensively, that could be a lot of testing for your testers (if you're lucky enough to have testers).  :)

Plus, if you're using plug-ins, you're not guaranteed that they're going to be compatible with the newer versions.

There are a lot of reasons why people are still on older versions.  I'm sure others will post other reasons.

Comment: But thats exactly WHY I would think it's important to use the latest version!!! because plugins might break, so you should keep updated.. so when you want to use another plugin, that NEW one will work.. i assume there is more backward compatibility than there is "forward compatibility"

Comment: But if you've built an application that uses a plug-in that depends on 1.5.1 for example, you can't just upgrade to 1.6 because that plug-in may break.  Not to pick on a component, but I posted a question recently and I was using 1.6 with a certain plugin, and it wasn't working because it only was supporting 1.5.2.  I couldn't upgrade to 1.6 because of that...or I would have to rewrite parts of my app.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing harm in always upgrading to latest JQuery that is realeased unless you dont want to change your legacy code in case some of the features in the old version are depricated.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've ever had to use an old version of jQuery, was when a jQuery plugin I was using broke due to changes in the new release.  Normally most plugin's do a good job working with the latest and greatest, but there was some big changes between 1.3 -> 1.4 -> 1.5 that had a few of my plugins down for a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

New versions of JQuery sometimes don't keep backward compatibility.